# Looking for Eloquent equivalent to this basic query using "DISTINCT YEAR(created_at)"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel and having now a hard to select 'DISTINCT YEAR' from "created_at" column.

Comment: lets see what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

You want to use this : `groupby` it can be used in `Query Builder`. The following like so:

```
$info = DB::table('tablename')
            ->select('id','name', 'email')
            ->groupBy('createdat')
            ->get();
```

Or query

```
SELECT DISTINCT `tablename` FROM `createdat`
```

And in eloquent.

```
$info = User::select('tablename')->distinct()->get()
```

Further reading:
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/the-sql-select-distinct-statement

https://laravel.io/forum/08-27-2014-looking-for-eloquent-equivalent-to-this-basic-query-using-distinct

http://laragems.com/post/eloquent-cheat-sheet